# Programming puzzle - drawing an inverted triangle

Tags: c++

The original question was to create a triangle out of hashes like this:

```
########
 ######
  ####
   ##
```

I decided to split the triangle in half and create half of each shape. Right now I have the code to create this shape:

```
####
###
##
#
```

code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main () {
    for (int row = 1; row <= 4; row++) {
        for (int hashNum = 1; hashNum <= 5 - row; hashNum++) {
            cout << "#";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to create the other half of the shape. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Here's a hint : write whitespaces before hashes according to the row number.

Comment: What else does the first output have besides #... that should make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very step-by-step way to do it. Note there are more elegant ways to do this, namely recursion comes to mind.

```
#include <iostream>  

void DrawTriangle(unsigned int rows)
{
    // Loop over the rows
    for(unsigned int spaces = 0; spaces < rows; ++spaces)
    {
        // Add the leading spaces
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < spaces; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << ' ';
        }
        // Add the hash characters
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < (rows - spaces)*2; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << '#';
        }
        // Add the trailing spaces
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < spaces; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << ' ';
        }
        // Add a newline to complete the row
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    DrawTriangle(4);
    return 0;
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/SRzvch)

```
########
 ###### 
  ####  
   ##
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure: treat the blank area as a triangle of spaces, and double the width of your current triangle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would consider the parameters of your problem. You are trying to draw a triangle of n rows of height with ascii chars. Considering that you take off one char on each side of the row on the next line, the minimum width of the base of your triangle is 2*(n-1)+1. For example, if you have n=3:

```
#####
 ###
  #
```

Doing it this way your triangle shape will be better, with only one '#' at the bottom. After that the program is more straightforward. you can make something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void DrawInvTri(unsigned int nrows)
{
    unsigned int ncols= (nrows-1)*2+1;

    for (int i=0; i<nrows; i++)
    {
        // Write spaces before tri
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<i; j++)
            cout << " ";
        // Write actual tri chars
        for (unsigned int k=i; k<(ncols - i); k++)
            cout << "#";
        // Next line
        cout << endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    DrawInvTri(5);
    DrawInvTri(3);
    DrawInvTri(4);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: *"Doing it this way your triangle shape will be better, with only one '#' at the bottom"* I don't think they have a choice on the format of the triangle, it looks like a homework assignment. If they produce the triangle that you suggest, they will likely be marked incorrect.